# how to input a respond to prompt of a command by python?

Tags: python, console-application, prompt

I ma running a Python code utilizing from prompt commands. It sometimes conflicts with the existing files and says

```
File 'outputs/g/Charlotte_s_Web_2006_-_Trailer.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
```

where the file name is changing.

Is it possible to capture that question and input `N` as an answer constantly on Python?

Comment: Please post the relevant section of your code. It will improve the likelihood of finding an answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on some UNIX variant, you can do

```
yes N | <program>
```

which feeds a never-ending stream of "N"s to the program.

If you want to control a console-driven program from Python, consider using `pexpect`. This library enables very simple interaction:

```
import pexpect
pexpect.spawn("<cmd>")
while 1:
    child.expect(r'\[y/N\]')
    child.sendline('N')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python I would've though you could just look at the source... use Find to get to the line it inputs at and replace it with = "N".

As for capturing it I dont fully understand what you mean but I think it would be obvious, when you look at the source, where the variable is coming from and you could just save it to a file using the standard functions.